# Error accessing onion service websites

Tags: configuration, onion-routing, network-configuration

When I access sites on the onion network, I get the following e**rror: [warn] Onion address [scrubbed] requested from a port with .onion disabled** how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your tor proxy's socks port is configured with the `NoOnionTraffic` option (search for `NoOnionTraffic` in [tor's man page](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/tor/tor.1.en.html)). You need to remove this option in order to visit onion websites.